# script tag not working with react site , when used in index.html

Tags: reactjs

I was working on a hobby project in react,  [I want to implement something like this](https://codepen.io/wind_hill/pen/rLAKLx)

but It won't work with me using the javascript(putting it in a script tag) in the index.html,
I think it has something to do with the DOM, if you could explain what's going on here that would be nice.

```
document.getElementById('div1').style.visibility = "hidden";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you'd want to instead use hooks to accomplish things involving changing element state. Specifically, you could use a piece of dynamic state with the `useState` hook to control that div's visibility. For example:

```
const [divVisibility, setDivVisibility] = useState("visible");

// Some function that updates the visibility
const someFunction = () => {
  setDivVisiblity("hidden");
}

return (
  <div style={{ visibility: divVisibility }}>
    ...
  </div>
)
```

Alternatively, if you really want to access the HTML element object within a React component (which typically is less recommended other than for specific use cases, which perhaps yours would be), you could use the [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook. This gives you a "ref", aka a reference, to the underlying HTML element. This might look something like this:

```
const divRef = useRef();

// Some function that updates the visibility
const someFunction = () => {
  if (divRef.current) {
    divRef.current.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}

return (
  <div ref={divRef}>
    ...
  </div>
)
```

Comment: please look into the link I have provided I want to implement full javascript present in that codepen.